# Indexation in ElasticSearch slowing down after each chunk

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

Actively trying to index a lot of documents (65000 for the record) through bulk export with a chunk size of 300 documents. Here are the following results :

chunk 1: 15s  (15sec)

chunk 2: 25s  (10sec)

chunk 3: 34s  (9 sec)

chunk 4: 1m03 (29 sec)

chunk 5: 1m42 (39sec)

chunk 6: 2m30 (48sec)

chunk 7: 3m45 (75sec)

chunk 8: 4m44 (59sec)

chunk 9: 6m02 (78 sec)

chunk 10: 7m33 (91 sec)

chunk 11: 9m17 (104 sec)

chunk 12: 11m09(112 sec)

chunk 13: 13m19(130 sec)

Chunk ~33 : 109m

The beginning speed is around 1200 documents per minute, but continuously drop. 
The estimated time for this batch is around 60 hours.. That's way too much and i guess something is wrong on my side. I tried to desactive the auto-refresh but it seems Elastic keep validating something before inserting since it take more and more time for each chunk..

Some details :

Elastic VM with 6gb of RAM
CPU running at 100%
~95% RAM used
A document consist of three nested beans, with a total of 31 fields

Thanks for your future help, I desperately need it.

Edit : node stats ->

https://jsonblob.com/f9c2703c-1f7a-11e7-a0ba-a71eee191178

Comment: Can you share what you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_nodes/stats` ?

Comment: Sure but it's a bit long, how can i link it without being restricted by Stackoverflow ?

Comment: You can share the results on github or some other online public sharing site, such as https://jsonblob.com/

Comment: Here you go : https://jsonblob.com/f9c2703c-1f7a-11e7-a0ba-a71eee191178